# Strange bug with string interpolation

Tags: regex, scala, string-interpolation

I'm getting a strange error with the following code.

I have a class `Example`, with a companion object, in which I have defined a string, `SIGN`. In class `Example` I have a method there I create a regular expression, and I use string interpolation so that I can use `SIGN` to build my regular expression.

This compiles, but I get a strange error at runtime. Is this a Scala bug? I'm using Scala 2.10.3 (on Windows 7).

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Example {
  import Example._
  def regex = s"""$SIGN?\d+""".r
}

object Example {
  private val SIGN = """(\+|-)"""
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Example
defined module Example

scala> val e = new Example
e: Example = Example@77c957d9

scala> e.regex
scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape character at index 1 in "?\d+"
        at scala.StringContext$.treatEscapes(StringContext.scala:229)
        at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:90)
        at scala.StringContext$$anonfun$s$1.apply(StringContext.scala:90)
        at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:123)
        at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:90)
        at Example.regex(<console>:9)
```

Comment: @raina77ow That also doesn't work, I get the same exception.

Comment: It looks like you're seeing some version of [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476), maybe? Plain old `s"$SIGN?\\d+".r` should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, it works with `\\\`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Please submit your comment as an answer, then I'll accept that as the answer to my question.

Comment: @TravisBrown Ok! (SO tells me I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer).

Comment: What you want is `r"""$SIGN?\d+"""`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the stack trace carefully, I see what's happening.

You can see that the method `s` is executed on the string, which handles the replacement of `$SIGN`. That method encounters the `\d` in the string and apparently tries to translate this; see the call to `treatEscapes` in the stack trace. The `treatEscapes` method doesn't recognize `\d` and throws an exception.

It can be fixed by writing `\\d` in the string, but that defeats the whole purpose of having a triple-quoted string...

Conclusion: It seems like string interpolation and triple-quoted strings interfere with each other. I'd say this is a Scala bug. (Why does the `s` method treat escapes?).

*edit* - This indeed looks like bug [SI-6476](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476) as Travis Brown pointed out in a comment.

Comment: Would be nice to submit to Scala project a better error message (just took 1 hour to find this little stupid bug). the message would give the workaround, not the best thing ever, but would help...

Comment: The code is getting touched, so now would be a good time to make a suggestion. But it's pretty hard to guess the workaround. Maybe a verbose mode to show the normal string escapes. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3695

Comment: @pommedeterresautee see my prev comment.  Also, SI-6476 is the opposite issue, people complaining that escaped quote is not supported for ordinary s"". I'd guess you want escaping for really basic stuff, s"""$a\n$b""". Odersky said what a clear win the feature was, despite his doubts, and yet people are irked by all sorts of edge cases.

Comment: The workaround I have used and described in the main message is to escape with two slashes instead of one. If it was said in the exception message it would help dev. It probably doesn't cover all the case but covering 80% of the crash would be great.

Comment: @pommedeterresautee I added the 8 esc chars it takes to the msg in my PR. I'll try to add s.t. like "use \\ for literal \". There was a similar change for f"%" to "use %% for literal %".

Comment: @pommedeterresautee Just realized that `f"a\"` says: `error: Trailing '\' escapes nothing.` I added that sort of extended check to f some months ago.